# using QtQuickComponents for S60 5th edition handsets

Tags: qt

How can I use QtQuickComponents for S60_5th devices ? I have a project that uses QtQuickComponents , It works fine for Symbian_Anna devices, but the application couldnt run on S60_5th devices , can any body help me